# Angular 2 rc5 router match X subcategories

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Using the new router in Angular 2 rc5 and have a common route I'm unsure how to write.

I need an url that's something like:

http://localhost:3000/store/{category}/{product-name}

This seems simple enough until I add in that I'm looking for there to be potentially multiple sub categories like (without us knowing how many there possibly are):

http://localhost:3000/store/{category 1}/{sub category 2}/{sub category 3}..../{product-name}

How can i create a path that matches against both the sub categories and the product. Is it something using pathMatch somehow other than "full"?

### standard app.routing.ts

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { 
          path: '/store/:cat', 
          component: CategoryComponent 
        },
        { 
          path: '/store/:cat/:product', 
          component: ProductComponent
        }
    ];
```

Comment: see @Godfather solution below. What caught me out on this is that there's the router-outlet of app component then a second router-outlet in a secondary component that allows the child routes to be served and collected. Then using ActivatedRoutes you can determine more data such as the urlSegments and do with those what you like to reach this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code:

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
     { 
       path: 'store', 
       component: StoreHomeComponent,
       children: [
         {
          path: '**',
          component: ProductComponent
         }]
     }];
```

StoreHomeComponent:

```
    @Component({
       template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
    })
    export class StoreHomeComponent {}
```

This code is not tested either, but it should work

Comment: Thanks @Godfather this seems to not work either. Can't seem to get the wildcard to work in this condition or under children or in a sub-route/sub-module way either.

Comment: @lostincode i am updated my answer, hope this one works well :)

Comment: Hey @Godfather not having any luck getting the wildcard to work anywhere other than in root. So far only way I can see of doing it is using wildcard at route then using activatedRoute and checking URL and then putting a switch in there to check what the urlSegments are... which is basically building your own router again on top of the router.... surely there must be a better way than this?

Comment: yeah, the way you did it works but it was quite messy. Can you please give me error message displayed on above approach?

Comment: Right! Got it! ok, so in this method we effectively have the router-outlet that lives in the app component to serve storeHomeComponent to and in turn the storehomecomponet is effectively a wrapper with another router-outlet in to serve the productcomponent into (which can use the activatedroutes to determine what to do with that address). I had missed out that wrapper router-outlet in the StoreHomeComponent! Thanks @Godfather you saved my day!