# angular 2 RC5 routerlink Link Parameters Array is encoding entities

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So i am using this method
[Angular 2 rc5 router match X subcategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149927/angular-2-rc5-router-match-x-subcategories)
to use 1-infinite subcategories under some route.
It works. But when i use Link Parameters Array to create link in my template using
`[routerLink]="['/edit',nav.href]"`
and lets say nav.href contains 'category/category/category', the result looks like this href="/edit/category%2Fcategory%2Fcategory".

It was OK in RC4.

Can i turn this entities encoding off?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you can disable encoding.  Try this: `['/edit', ...nav.href.split('/')]` -- i.e., split up your string then use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Comment: Mark great idea! Unfortunately angular compiler does not like spread syntax here. But with your advice i have succesfully used this `[routerLink]="('/editor' + nav.href).split('/')"`. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the right approach is to split variable containing entities.

`[routerLink]="variable.split('/')"`

In this particular scenario i had to join strings first

`[routerLink]="('/editor' + nav.href).split('/')"`